# TSVN cannot connect to repo

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

I have used TSVN TortoiseSVN for many years in a Windows Virtual Machine. I have never had any issues like this before. Now when I try to do a commit, the commit window hangs.

Here is the blow by blow:

- perform a merge between branches using TSVN. That works normally.
- commit the newly merged changes
- the commit window hangs indefinitely
- click "Cancel"; TSVN says "could not connect to the repo"
- reboot windows virtual machine
- the commit now functions normally
- repeat the above, and it happens every time

There is some discussion on the web, but very old. One place said to clear the "Saved Data".

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs in our office when the repository server becomes unavailable from the client. also sometimes when the server IP been changed It occurs and we just do `Reallocate` to the valid IP and everything be okay.

Also you said the commit now functions normally after reboot windows virtual machine. The sounds like the server's network adapter configuration such as (`DHCP` or `DNS`, ...) may needs be configured.

I hope to be helpful for you:)